# Empty array is not empty

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a function which looks like this:

```
public returnData(): { points: Array<{ x: number, y: number }>, pointsCount: Array<number> } {
    return {
        points: [{x: 0, y: 1},{x: 1, y: 2 }],
        pointsCount: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
 }
```

And if I will write something like:

```
let mydata = this.returnData();
```

It would be the Object contains two arrays: {points:Array(2), pointsCount:Array(4)}

But, if I will change it:

```
public returnData(): { points: Array<{ x: number, y: number }>, pointsCount: Array<number> } {

     let localdata: Array<{x:number, y:number}> = [];
     let local_points_count: Array<number> = [];

     localdata.push([{x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:2}]);
     local_points_count.push([1,2,3,4]);

    return {
        points: localdata,
        pointsCount: local_points_count
    }
 }
let mydata = this.returnData();
```

will return {points:Array(0),pointsCount:Array(0)}. And if I will check out the data in Chrome console it is not Empty.

Help me, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pushing an array into an array. Try this

```
localdata.push({x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:2});
local_points_count.push(1,2,3,4);
```